# Emulate Powerpoint behavior: Show additional cell content with each click

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to emulate powerpoint animation behavior during a presentation with *Mathematica*?

Considering a notebook with cell of numbered items or even several cells, is it possible to display a new cell or item with each click (or key press), probably in presentation mode?

Comment: Have you tried the slide show document style? Try `File > New > Slide Show ...`.

Comment: Do you want to convert every cell into a separate slide / display cells in a notebook sequentially /...? Then you should update your question and explain in more detail what you want to do.

Comment: How about if you start off with only the first cell opened, then open the second, then the third, etc. You can do this directly by double clicking on the cell brackets at the right of the cells.

Comment: Wono, I did a rather drastic facelift of your question based on what I think you want to do (and what I would consider useful for others, too). Hopefully this concurs with your intentions. Not sure if there is a simple answer to this other than "No", but time will tell.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
disks=Table[Disk[{Sin[phi],Cos[phi]},0.1], {phi, 0,2 Pi(9/10), 2 Pi/10}];

DynamicModule[{clicks=1},
    EventHandler[
        Graphics[
            Dynamic@Take[disks, clicks], 
            PlotRange->1.2{{-1,1}, {-1,1}}],
        "MouseClicked":>(
            clicks=Mod[clicks+1, Length@disks,1])]
]
```

or simply

```
FlipView[Graphics[#, PlotRange -> 1.2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] & /@ disks]
```

Ooor

```
Options[generateCellByCellNotebook]={"Replace"->False};

generateCellByCellNotebook[nbo_NotebookObject, op:OptionsPattern[]]:=
    generateCellByCellNotebook[NotebookGet@nbo, op];

generateCellByCellNotebook[Notebook[{cell1_, restCells___}, opts___], OptionsPattern[]]:=
    Module[{newNbo, newNb},
    newNb= Notebook[{cell1}, opts, 
        NotebookEventActions:>{"MouseClicked":>
            With[{snb=SelectedNotebook[]},
            With[{
                allCells=CurrentValue[snb, {TaggingRules, "Powerpointify", "RestCells"}],
                counter=CurrentValue[snb, {TaggingRules, "Powerpointify","NextCellCounter"}, 1]},
                    If[counter<=Length@allCells,
                        If[OptionValue["Replace"], NotebookDelete@Last@Cells@snb];
                        SelectionMove[snb, After, Notebook];
                        NotebookWrite[snb, allCells[[counter]]];
                        ++CurrentValue[snb, {TaggingRules, "Powerpointify","NextCellCounter"}];
                    ]   
            ]
            ]}
    ];
    newNbo=NotebookPut[newNb];
    CurrentValue[newNbo, {TaggingRules, "Powerpointify","RestCells"}]={restCells};
]
```

You would use it by doing `generateCellByCellNotebook[someNotebookObject, Replace->True]` if you want the cell replaced on each click or `Replace->False` (default) if you want to append them

Conclusion: I'm not exactly sure what you mean :P

Comment: Wow, big +1. One flipview broke down though when I called generateCellByCellNotebook[EvaluationNotebook[]].

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `FlipView[]`... amazing!